# jQuery object loses jQueryness

Tags: jquery, liferay

Liferay 6.1; jQuery 1.11.3

```
var selectProduct = $('#selectProduct');
var selectVersion = $('#selectVersion');
// selectProduct instanceof jQuery = TRUE
selectProduct.change(function() {
    // selectProduct instanceof jQuery = FALSE
    $.get("<%getVersionsURL%>", {"product": selectProduct.val()}).done(function(data) {
            selectVersion.html("<option value=\"\"></option>");
            selectVersion.append(data);
}
```

The above code will not run from a .jsp on my liferay server. I get an error 'selectProduct.val is not a function'.

It seems that inside the .change function, selectProduct is no longer a jQuery object. `selectProduct instanceof jQuery` returns false inside the function, but true out of it. My current fix is to add the line

```
selectProduct = $(selectProduct);
```

Or to re-wrap the variable every time I use it in the event handler.
Why is the reference changing? When I test a similar scenario on JSFiddle, there are no problems.

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/81nh4n93/)

Comment: Something, in code you're not showing, is modifying `selectProduct`.

Comment: Something else must be changing your object, so that the jQuery reference is now broken. The fix is to use $(this) and fresh jQuery selectors inside events and not rely on variables.

Comment: Must be something Liferay is doing behind the scenes as that's the only JavaScript I'm running.. fresh selectors it is!